# How to check if GWT RequestFactory's proxy is frozen?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

This is the way I do it now:

```
try {
  itemProxy.setQuantity(20);
} catch (IllegalStateException e){
  itemProxy = context.edit(itemProxy);
  table.replaceProxy(index, itemProxy);

  itemProxy.setQuantity(20);
}
```

Is there any other way than catching the exception? I know that proxy has "frozen" property, because I see it in the Eclipse debugger. But I can't cast the proxy to any class or AutoBean interface to read the value of frozen property.

Answer (score 2):

You can try that :

```
boolean frozen = com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean(itemProxy).isFrozen();
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that `edit()` will return the proxy if it's already been edited (in the same `RequestContext` that is), why don't you simply `edit()` it unconditionally?

---

As a side note, I don't quite understand how you can be in a situation where you don't know whether your proxy is edited or not. That's probably the crux of the problem; exceptions should remain an exceptional case (that sounds like stating the obvious, but it's particularly true in GWT, and JS in general), and code flow shouldn't have a "er, well, I'm not sure what state I'm in, so let's try that" path.

Answer (score 0):

Once you call edit on the proxy then only it will be mutable otherwise it is frozen. To know whether it frozen you can use the answer given by FLorent Bayle

```
boolean frozen = com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean(itemProxy).isFrozen();
```